# hibernate +Java query syntax issue

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting erro while executing the query.and No proper error are there in the logs.It only says. Error in query `findAllfundSalesCreditCalc`.Can anybody help what wrong in it.

```
@NamedQuery(name="findAllfundSalesCreditCalc",query="select distinct FCM from SubFund SF" +
    "join Class C on C.id = SF.id" +
    "join SC_Class SCC where SCC.classId = C.id" +
    "left join FundSalesCreditCalcMethod  FCM where FCM.SubFundId = SF.id")
```

Comment: try with `SELECT distinct SF.FCM FROM SubFund SF...`. On the other hand, you should use `namelCase` for your entities variables. It's a good practice and convention.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing whitespaces:

```
@NamedQuery(name="findAllfundSalesCreditCalc",query=
    "select distinct FCM from SubFund SF" +
    " join Class C on C.id = SF.id" +
    " join SC_Class SCC where SCC.classId = C.id" +
    " left join FundSalesCreditCalcMethod  FCM where FCM.SubFundId = SF.id")
//   ^ 
//   | here
```

Just because you put a concatenated string on a new line in Java doesn't mean that the (Java) whitespace is reflected in your SQL query.